# Parsing JSON with shortened keys in C#

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I'm porting a project from Android to Windows Phone 8 and can't find any info on how to specify which JSON key maps to which object field.

The Android code uses *Google GSON* and the `SerializedName` annotation to map `em` in the JSON to the `email` field in the object.

I'm also controlling which fields are [de]serialized using the `Expose` annotation. How would I go about doing these same things in my Windows Phone 8 project?

I'd absolutely hate to use a class that looks like this:

```
public sealed class SomeData
{
    public string em { get; set; }
    public string un { get; set; }
    public string fn { get; set; }
    public int tz { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark properties with DataMember attribute to explicitly specify desired name.

```
    [DataMember(Name = "em")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```